# Laravel: Undefined variable $test in production but runs fine locally

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to render a simple array of objects in a blade component. My code works fine on my local machine, but throws an "undefined variable" error in production. I'm using Laravel Forge and Digital Ocean to serve my website. PHP versions match in both environments.

```
timeline.php

<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class timeline extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.timeline');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return [
            [
                'year' => '1826',
                'desc' => "Built during 1826 and 27, the Cascade Locks became the site of the city's first industrial valley.
                            The same topography that presented an obstacle for the canal builders provided waterpower for a string of
                            industries that soon lined the canal. This new village, founded by Dr. Eliakim Crosby, with help from Simon Perkins,
                            was called Cascade. It later became what we now call North Akron. The Cascade Locks were constructed of huge blocks of sandstone,
                            sawed and chiseled to shape. The locks have a width of 15 feet, and they are up to 90 feet long. The source of
                            canal water was, and still is the Portage Lakes.",

                'img' => 'cascade-valley-1882.jpg',
                'alt' => 'Opening Day'
            ],
            [...],
```

```
timeline.blade.php

<!-- component -->
<div class="container bg-green-700 bg-opacity-10 mx-auto">
    <div class="relative wrap py-8 px-4 lg:p-10">
        @foreach ($test as $key => $item)
            <div class="mb-8 flex justify-between flex-col-reverse
                {{ $key % 2 == 0 ? 'lg:flex-row-reverse' : 'lg:flex-row' }}
                items-center w-full right-timeline pb-4">
                <div class="w-5/12"></div>
                <div class="z-20 flex items-center order-1 bg-green-700 bg-opacity-30 shadow-xl p-3 rounded-full mb-4 lg:mb-0">
                    <h1 class="mx-auto font-semibold text-lg text-black">{{ $item['year'] }}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-green-800 text-white rounded-lg shadow-xl w-full lg:w-5/12 px-6 py-4"
                    style="text-shadow: 0px 0.25px white;">
                    <h3 class="mb-3 font-extrabold text-xl">Headline</h3>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-snug tracking-wide text-opacity-100 mb-4">
                        {{ $item['desc'] }}
                    </p>
                    <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/pages/history/{{ $item['img'] }}" alt="{{ $item['alt'] }}"
                        class="m-auto mb-2 w-full h-72 object-cover object-center rounded-md" />
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

```
history.blade.php

@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

    <div id="history" class="h-80 w-full relative flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <div class="absolute">
            <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/pages/history/canal-timeline.png" alt="Canal Timeline Icon"
                class="object-cover object-center" style="z-index: 1;" />
        </div>
        <div class="h-1/2 w-full bg-gray-100"></div>

        <div class="h-1/2 w-full bg-green-700 bg-opacity-20"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="pt-6 pb-6 lg:pb-14 bg-green-700 bg-opacity-20">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="text-center">
                <p class="mt-2 text-3xl leading-8 font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl">
                    Cascade Locks History
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <x-timeline />


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#history').offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        });

    </script>
@endsection
```

Again, this works perfectly fine locally. Only when I access my site in production is the error thrown. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which variable is undefined?

Comment: @StefanPavlov: $test

Comment: We do not see how you pass the test variable in your controller to the view.

Comment: @StefanPavlov: Is this not how I would pass it, and if not, why would this work on my local machine?

foreach ($test as $key => $item)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public function render()
{
    return view('components.timeline');
}
```

to this

```
public function render()
{
    return view('components.timeline')->with('test', $this->test());
}
```

And also you cam make the test method private, if you are not using it anywhere else.

You can also put this before foreach

```
@if (isset($test))
```

Comment: Made the changes you suggested and I'm still getting the following:

[2021-03-17 15:54:51] production.ERROR: Undefined variable: test
{"exception":"[object] (Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Undefined variable: test

I do not get an error and I can load the page correctly locally.

Comment: try to dump the variable with {{ dd($test) }} in blade and dd($this->test()) in controller before return statement. You can also put @if(isset($test)) before foreach loop in the blade